# Does the gambler's fallacy apply in this scenario?

Tags: probability

An example of the gambler's fallacy:

Say I flip a coin ten times, and the first five times are all tails. People would think that in order to "even out" the probabilities, there will be a higher probability of heads compared to tails in the next five flips. This incorrect (and obviously dangerous) thinking has led many gamblers to lose their money, hence "the gambler's fallacy."

Now, consider this scenario:

I have an algorithm that can predict whether a coin will land on heads or tails, with 50% accuracy. I ask Bob to flip a coin ten times, and record the results. The results of the first five flips are then compared to what my algorithm predicted.

Let's say the algorithm got every single prediction wrong in the first five flips. Does this mean that there is a higher probability that the algorithm will be correct in the remaining five flips?

I'm not sure whether the gambler's fallacy applies here, so correct me if I'm wrong......

Comment: Not sure this is clear.  I can predict the coin with $50\%$ accuracy just by blindly guessing.  Obviously you can't get any information at all out of that "predictor".

Comment: My point is that this depends on the predictor.  To take a different one, suppose that I know the result of the toss with certainty, but each time I toss a $10$ sided die and if it comes up $10$ I lie to you but otherwise I tell you the truth.  That predictor is pretty good!  $90\%$ accuracy, in fact.  But each prediction is independent of all the others so, yes, in this case the gambler's fallacy would apply.  My guess is that this sort of predictor is what you are thinking of.

Comment: I remember a story of a guy would predict the sex of your child using a nonsense technique.  He had a no fuss money back policy if he was wrong.  Nonetheless, he made good money.

Comment: The opposite fallacy is the "hot hands" theory.  If the first five flips are all tails, then "tails" is hot, so you should bet in favor of tails in the future.  https://www.racingbetting.com/strategy/hot-hand-phenomenon/

Answer (score 1):

50% probability does not mean that if you flip the coin 10 times, it will be heads five times and tails five times. It only means that the heads to tails  will approach the expected value the more you repeat the experiment.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers

In your case, I don't see why the probability would be higher in the next five flips.